# Value of type 'AVCaptureFileOutput' has no member 'delegate'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

The documentation https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturefileoutput indicates a delegate property exists for AVCaptureFileOutput.

But the following code

```
    let vfo = AVCaptureFileOutput()
    vfo.delegate = self
```

give the error "Value of type 'AVCaptureFileOutput' has no member 'delegate'"

I am looking to use a AVCaptureFileOutputDelegate for a AVCaptureMovieFileOutput instance.

Any pointer will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link to the [`delegate` property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturefileoutput/1388718-delegate) on the page you quoted (or look at the `#if`s around it in the header file), and you'll notice that property is for macOS only, not iOS. Thus, when you're in a project targeting iOS, that property doesn't exist.

iOS doesn't let you both receive sample buffers during capture *and* record to a file with the same session -- you can have an `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` or an `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, but not both. If you just want delegate callbacks about movie file capture progress, use [`startRecording(toOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturefileoutput/1387224-startrecording) and adopt [`AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate) instead. If you want sample buffers, use `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to receive them and `AVAssetWriter` for lower-level file output.

Comment: I'm simply trying to record a video with audio and get the audio power level at the same time.  Is there a combination of classes that allows this?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the pointer to AVAssetWriter.  I was able to find RosyWriter sample https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html.  The modified CaptureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer to capture the audio averagePowerLevel did the trick of getting a recorded movie and getting simultaneous audio levels.

But is there a more striped down example of its use?  My attempts to strip out the renderers, which do the video manipulation, have only broken the sample.